# How to call the compiled asp files

Tags: asp.net

I have a website to deploy and I have compiled it but please let me know how can  I call the compiled files when a request comes respective to the page

Answer (score 0):

use the INCLUDE FILE statement

```
<!--#include file="config.asp"-->
```